# How to add a class to a <li> generated by PHP using jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I have number of `<li>` generated by PHP. I want every row to display only 4 `<li>` and the last `<li>` in that row to have a class of `noMarginRight`?

```
<ul>
  <li>sample</li>
  <li>sample</li>
  <li>sample</li>
  <li>sample here</li>

  <li>sample</li>
  <li>sample</li>
  <li>sample</li>
  <li>sample here</li>

  <li>sample</li>
  <li>sample</li>
  <li>sample</li>
  <li>sample here</li>
</ul>
```

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Why doesn't PHP do this?

Comment: @Chris, I had to edit *your* edit to remove the extra 'Thanks' that you added. Although very useful in real life, this kind of friendly banter is *not* appropriate to add to questions or answers on this website... especially when they are *not* yours, so please refrain doing this in your future edits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [:nth-child](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)

```
$('ul li').filter(':nth-child(4n), :last-child').addClass('noMarginRight')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/s5pX2/)

If you are sure that always the number if rows are multiple of 4 then

```
$('ul li:nth-child(4n)').addClass('noMarginRight')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/S54v5/)

Answer (score 4):

I got that what you are trying to do, you want every 4th `li` *not* to have `margin-right`, so no need to assign any `class` for that, you can achieve this using pure CSS, as you have tagged the question for CSS as well..

```
ul li:nth-child(4n) {
   margin-right: 0;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/634fm/) *(Used `color` property to show how selector works)*

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/634fm/1/) *(`margin` equivalent demonstration)*

Answer (score 0):

You can manage from PHP code, please try this way

```
     <ul>
    <?php
    $result = array("ads", "sdsa", "fsdfs", "fsdfsfsdf", "ffsfsf");
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($result as $k => $v) {
        ?>
        <li <?php echo (++$i % 4 == 0) ? "class=\"noMarginRight\"" : "" ?>><?php echo $v; ?></li>
<?php } ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply same name attribute to the last li of each row and then use **$("your li selector on the basis of name" ).addClass( "myClass yourClass" );**

for eg: $( "li[name='last']" ).addClass( "noMarginRight" );

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned you using php for displaying the output, here is a way you can do with php,

```
    $counter    = 0;   

    while ($line = mysql_fetch_object($result)) 
    { 

              if($counter %4 != 0) 
                {

                    echo "<li  class='noMarginRight'>";
                    echo "your output";
                    echo '</li>';

                }
                else
                {
                    echo "<li>";
                    echo "your output";
                    echo '</li>';
                }

   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

## CSS Only Method

Just for completeness here is a pure CSS3 way of doing what you want to achieve:

```css
ul
{
    -moz-column-count:4; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-column-count:4; /* Safari and Chrome */
    column-count:4;
    -moz-column-gap:30px; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-column-gap:30px; /* Safari and Chrome */
    column-gap:30px;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>sample</li>
  <li>sample</li>
  <li>sample</li>
  <li>sample here</li>

  <li>sample</li>
  <li>sample</li>
  <li>sample</li>
  <li>sample here</li>

  <li>sample</li>
  <li>sample</li>
  <li>sample</li>
  <li>sample here</li>
</ul>
```